# Error in ExecuteReader

Tags: ado.net

I am getting the following error message:

System.InvalidOperationException: ExecuteReader requires an open and available  Connection.   The connection's current state is Closed.

And here is my code:

```
public IDataReader ExecuteReader()
{
    IDataReader reader = null;

    try
    {
        this.Open();
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (handleErrors)
            strLastError = ex.Message;
        else
            throw;
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }

    return reader;
}
```

Does anyone know how I can resolve this?

Comment: Can you post your Open() method ?

Answer (score 1):

The Connection object that your SQLCommand is attached to has not been opened.  You must open the *connection* before you can query.

Something like this:

```
private static void OpenSqlConnection(string connectionString)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();

        var cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
        // Do your command access here.

    }
}
```